# Can a noun be an adverb?

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis, noun-phrases, adverbials, grammatical-roles

This question, which [I first posed on the ELL site a few weeks ago](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/168906/141), remains effectively unanswered. Although there an answer did finally get 
posted, it seemed to be more of a parody of an answer than a real one, 
to me at least.

So here goes; please consider this sentence:

> I can barely see a foot in front of me in this fog.

As a standalone sentence, it can’t be the answer to a question starting
with “What can you...” because “a foot” is here a unit of the length of
vision, and so a question it may be the answer to might be “How far can
you see in this fog?"

Would I be right saying that *barely° in this sentence modifies *can*
whereas *a foot* modifies *to see*? If so, does it mean that it plays the
role of an adverb? But can a noun be an adverb? If so, what type of adverb
is it in that sentence?

P.S. There’s a related post on the ELL site dealing with the role of *a 
foot* in a sentence, but it doesn’t seem to answer my question.

Comment: One easy way to test is to try to replace it with something you know is definitely an adverb, like _actually_ or _often_. How would you say that works?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet-- I'm not asking about "bearly" but about "a foot",

Comment: Yes, I realise that. But if it were functioning as an adverb, you should be able to exchange it for an adverb and still have a grammatical sentence.

Comment: I'll alter the example slightly: 'I can't see a foot in front of me' essentially has the same broad form as 'I can't see well' or 'I can't see to the other side of the river' (assuming 'a foot' isn't the kind usually found attached to a leg). Everything after 'see' in these examples shows the restriction on your seeing, and is thus an adverbial. Some call 'a mile' say in 'He walked a mile' an adverbial objective.

Comment: If you *aren't* actually asking "Can a noun be an adverb?" then you should clarify your question so it doesn't sound like that *is* what you're asking.

Comment: see a foot, means see 12 inches in front of me. How can that possibly be an adverb? These types of obvious questions really drive me batty (which is why I am an old bat).  "a foot" does not qualify  the verb see; it complements it. Sheesh.

Comment: Are you aware that *barely* is a [***negative polarity item***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item) in English? Compare: "I can see something", "I cannot see anything" and "I  can barely/hardly see anything". That means the negation is to the entire verb phrase, not to just one of the component verbs.

Comment: He can barely see one foot in front of himself. He can barely grasp one idea at a time. idea is adverbial?? Why wouldn't "see a distance in front of  [pronoun]"  (one foot) not be analogous to "grasp an idea". I could barely see him in front of me. Adverbial? He heartily grasped the idea. I can see ten feet in front of me. adverbial? Lots of knickers twisting going on .....I wanted to post patterns re this but hesitate....too many sour grapes.

Comment: "Because both the incident fast neutrons and the emerging /spl gamma/s penetrate fairly effectively, it ought to be possible to see some distance into the ground." Tell me, is distance not used like "see a foot" in the OP's question? The complement of see needn't be a thing. It can be a measurement of distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can barely **see a foot** in front of me in this fog.

A foot here in English means a single foot, one foot. One foot is a distance. The determiner a is often used in lieu of one.

**Barely** is an adverb, other adverbs would work here:

I can **almost** see a foot in front of me in this fog. [substitutions]
I can **hardly** see a foot  in front of me in this fog.

***Almost***, ***hardly*** and ***barely*** all qualify how the subject I in the sentence can see.  Therefore, they are adverbs. These adverbs are often pre-positioned, unlike well which is often post-positioned.

**To see a foot** is a perception of distance. A measurement of distance. To perceive a distance. See is perceive (Merriam Webster).

Here is a scientific example of this usage:

> Because both the incident fast neutrons and the emerging /spl gamma/s
>   penetrate fairly effectively, it ought to be possible to see some
>   distance into the ground.

Substitution for purposes of like structure: ***to see ten feet into the ground*** may be substituted in the text above. The seeing (perceiving) action is being performed by a detector.

The verb see means to perceive "with sight" and is transitive  here. foot and distance are its complements in the preceding examples. [direct object complement of the verb see]

Ergo,  foot is not an adverb or adverbial. One is hard pressed, furthermore, to see it as adverbial given the presence of barely in front of the verb to see.

to see a foot=to perceive a distance of one foot

The OP's sentence is the same as: 
I can barely **perceive a distance** of one foot in front of me in this fog.

Answer to question: No, the noun foot cannot be a adverb.

> [see some distance](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/731288/)

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

*Foot* is a noun here, not an adverb:

> 1. I can barely see **a foot in front of me** in this fog.

So the direct answer to your main question of “Can a noun be an
adverb?” is no, because a word cannot ever be **both** a noun and also an
adverb — ***at the same time.***

We know it’s a noun because it takes an article: ***a*** foot, meaning one foot. You cannot do that with adverbs. Adverbs can take *very*, but you could not say that you can barely see *very foot in front of you. That’s ungrammatical because *foot* is not an adverb. It’s a noun.

---

## Longer Answer

But at different times? Sure! It’s perfectly normal for the same-spelt
word to serve as a different part of speech in one sentence than in
other, dissimilar sentences.  For example, *fast* can be a noun *or* a verb *or* an
adjective *or* an adverb — provided these are in four different sentences.

Although quite honestly, I can't imagine a scenario under which *foot*
could **ever** be an adverb.  It’s almost always a noun, at least until it
comes time for you **to *foot* the bill**.

However, that’s **not** what’s happening in your sentence. In the same
way that the *to* in *to foot* tells you that the word *foot* is probably
being used as a verb in my footing-the-bill sentence, the words around
*foot* in your sentence give away that it must be a noun.

In particular,
you know that *foot* is definitely a noun because it’s the head of the
***noun phrase*** (hereafter abbreviated *NP*) *“a foot in front of me”*.
That NP begins with the indefinite article *a* in the NP’s determiner slot.

Syntactically, the NP *“a foot in front of me”* is composed of
the same sorts of components as in the NP *“a hand in front of me”*
or *“a wire in front of me”*. Imagine this sentence:

> The fog was so thick that I couldn't see a branch in front of me
>   until it smacked me in the face.

In both

- see a foot in front of me
- see a branch in front of me

You have a noun phrase with an article, the head noun, and
a prepositional phrase further describing that noun.

But in the *branch* case, that NP is serving the grammatical role of being
the verb *see*’s direct object. As you correctly observed, that’s not
what’s happening in your own sentence: nobody is seeing a foot. The
grammatical role of your NP is instead adverbial. It says **where** you
could barely see, not **what** you could barely see.

When the NP is acting as a verb’s direct object, it is not “modifying”
that verb. A verb’s arguments (such as its subject or its various objects) are not considered to be “modifiers” of that verb. They’re just arguments, not modifiers.

With the sentence that has the NP *“a branch in front of me”, if you exchange that whole NP with the pronoun *him*,
you still have an NP acting as the verb’s direct object:

2. I could barely see **a branch in front of me** in the fog.
3. I could barely see **him standing right in front of me** in the fog.

That's because the overall syntactic role of the NP has not changed, even
though *him* is a different part of speech than *branch* is. Neither of
those is “modifying” the verb; they are not acting adverbially. They’re just serving as the direct object, as an argument.

But your NP is **not** the verb’s direct object. Instead it is being used
to **describe** the verb just as any other adverbial expression might. Here
are several syntactically equivalent examples:

4. I couldn’t see **a foot in front of me** in the fog.
5. I couldn’t see **very far** in the fog.
6. I couldn’t see **clearly** in the fog.
7. I couldn’t see **well** in the fog.

Each constituent (that is, each sentence element) there which I’ve marked in bold is syntactically
equivalent — because each of those four is an adverbial use.
That is **not** the same thing as saying that each one is an adverb!

Parts of speech apply **only** to single words, never to longer phrases.
So you can’t say that *very far* “is” an adverb. It isn't. It's an
adverbial phrase. Here in *very far*, *far* actually is an adverb, but
in a *a foot*, the word *foot* is just a noun. If it were an adverb,
it would forbid determiners like *a* and accept the adverb *very* as
a modifier, but it does not.

Here’s another example:

8. He called me often.
9. He called me quickly.
10. He called me the first Friday of every month.

Although *often* and *quickly* are adverbs, the NP *“the first Friday of
every month”* certainly is not. But we can use that NP as an adverbial
modifer of the verb *call*.

It’s important not to confuse syntactic roles with parts of speech.  You
have to look at the larger grammar of the sentence to see that entire
multiword phrases can act as interchangeable syntactic constituents just as
much as a single word can be such.  The [Wikpedia article on
Adverbials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial) says:

> In English, adverbials most commonly take the form of adverbs, adverb
>   phrases, temporal noun phrases or prepositional phrases. Many types of
>   adverbials (for instance: reason and condition) are often expressed by
>   clauses.
>
> - *James answered immediately.* (adverb)
> - *James answered in English.* (prepositional phrase)
> - *James answered this morning.* (noun phrase)
> - *James answered in English because he had a foreign visitor.* (adverbial clause)
>
> An adverbial is a construction which modifies or describes verbs. When an
>   adverbial modifies a verb, it changes the meaning of that verb. Word
>   groups, which are also considered to be adverbials, can also modify verbs:
>   for example, a prepositional phrase, a noun phrase, a finite clause or a
>   non-finite clause.

There are no adverbs in the NP *this morning*, only a demonstrative and a
noun, but the entire phrase is still being used as an adverbial syntactic
constituent just as much as the adverb *immediately* was.

This is the same class of confusion as we see when people mistakenly call
gerunds “nouns”:

11. Giving me a ride home saved my life that day.
12. Friends saved my life that day.
13. She saved my life that day.
14. How and when I left saved my life that day.

There you see various different types of NPs, each acting as the subject of
the verb *saved*. Sure, *friends* is a noun, but *she* is a pronoun **not** a
noun — and *giving* is a verb **not** a noun. That doesn’t mean those NPs can’t
all be subjects. They can and are. They just aren’t all nouns is all.

Same with you and adverbs versus adverbials.

Just like how the NP *“giving me a ride”* is not an actual noun, your NP of
*“a foot in front of me*” is not an actual adverb.  That doesn't stop them
from serving as syntactic constituents in grammatical roles that in other
sentences could be filled by a single word of the appropropriate part of
speech. They’re always still noun phrases, not nouns or adverbs.

Comment: You had me going there. But now, after some deep thought, ...

Comment: ... I think that *a foot in front of me* is actually a preposition phrase (if you agree that *in front* is a compound preposition/PP). The NP *a foot* is behaving like a modifier of that PP. Consider *I couldn't see in front of me* / *I couldn't see far in front of me* / *I couldn't see two inches in front of me*.  It's very common for measure NPs to function as modifiers within PPs: *two years after the war / three feet beyond the wire / miles above the earth* etc. I don't know if I've persuaded you. Tons of useful and helpful grammar info in this post. (+1, but I' sure it's a PP)

Comment: Btw, Long Answer, para 3, *give away* perhaps? (instead of *give way*) [Or maybe that's a pond thing ...]

Comment: @Araucaria Yes thanks, it’s *give away*; we always say *yield* here for “give way”. :) If you see something coming a mile away, do you think there’s a preposition there somewhere?

Comment: For H&P there would be, because *away* is an intransitive preposition (it can take PP complements and other types but not NPs). However, in your particular example, it seems a bit weird/exceptional (a bit like *ago*) in that there it alomost *requires* a 'modifier' ...

Comment: @Araucaria Odd ideas worth every penny include how even though you can’t say *✱very ago* nor *✱very away* (evidentially suggesting those are not modifiers in the first place),  you **can** say *long ago* or *far away*. I have no idea what that makes those, but I know you can’t say *✱very worth every penny* either. I know that all formal grammars leak, but I always wonder whether such anomalies might be signs that our model sucks.

Comment: @Araucaria Just as you can be **running a few minutes *late***, you can also be **running run a few miles *behind***. In the *behind* case, it’s possible to add an argument, like *behind schedule* — but not in the *late* case. So those two aren’t the same kind of thing either. But I don’t think either is an object of the verb *running* the way *running a few miles* would have a simple NP object of *a few miles*. That additional *late* there at the end makes it...something else, just like adding an *away* or an *ago* makes their respective NPs something else. Me, I’m going with an adverbial NP.

Comment: I don't buy the adverbial syntactic constituent at all. And I don't understand why everyone is so keen to make it adverbial.

Comment: @Lambie Because in "I called him every Tuesday" the "every Tuesday" part is clearly an NP being used adverbially since it's a modifying phrase that says when. In "I couldn't see a foot in front of me" it's a modifying phrase saying where. It's not an object, provably so because you can add one: "I couldn't see the wall a foot in front of me." The wall is the object, not the foot.

Comment: That is not the same usage at all.  In the OP's sentence: "to see a foot in front of  me" means: to see a distance of one foot. So, it is the object.  Whereas yours is: I couldn't see a wall a foot in front of me is really: I couldn't see the wall [which was] a foot in front of me. An entirely different clause.

Comment: @Lambie That *foot* is **ɴᴏᴛ** the object of the verb *see* here because its **passive inversion is ungrammatical.** You can say *“I could barely see two feet in front of me”* but passive inversion yields nonsense, no matter whether that’s ✱ *“Two feet in front of me could barely be seen by me.”* or if it’s the more likely ✱ *“Two feet in front of me were barely seen by me.”*

Comment: @tchrist I can barely see [a distance of] two feet in front of me. A distance of two feet in front of me can barely be seen by me. Awkward certainly, but technically, it works. For me: to see a distance is like to see a fly. Plus it does not answer the quintessential questions: how, when, where etc. that an adverb must answer. I could barely see [a distance] of two feet clearly in front of me. It does answer the "what" question: What could I barely not see in front of me? A distance of two feet.  The elliptical distance makes the most sense to me.

Comment: @tschirst **I thought passive inversion only worked if it was clear what the "object" of "see" was** ? In, "I couldn't see a foot in front of me" "of me" is indirectly related to the verb "see" through its preposition "of"--"of me" is a non-core complement of "see" and the NP "me" is the oblique (pg 216, CaGEL). But does that make "a foot" of "see" a direct object and therefore  "me" as inadmissible as the object of "see"? The point of an oblique is that "me" could be the object of the verb or the preposition *of*.

Answer (score -1):

NP stands for noun phrase 
PP stands for prepositional phrase

---

> I can barely see [a foot], [in front of me], [in this fog.]

- [A foot] is a NP

---

- [In front of me] is a PP with a special type of NP compliment called
  the oblique genitive NP compliment

**Referenced from Chapter 5: Nouns and Noun phrases of CaGEL: Head and phrasal genitives**

This PP has a special type of complement called the genitive NP.
`front of me` is an oblique genitive noun phrase, where the head genitive is realised as the pronoun `me`. And the phrasal genitive for me is `me's`.

Compare

> a) [**my**] facial expression - genitive NP
>
> b) [**the man opposite me’s**] facial expression - phrasal genitive
>
> In the head genitive construction (a) the pronoun is realised as my,
>   but in the phrasal genitive me’s in (b).
>
> pg 479-480

> [65]
>
> ib [the man opposite me’s] facial expression
>
> iia [my friend’s] father
>
> **iib [a friend of mine’s] father**
>
> In (iia) and (iib), we have 2 genitives: in (iia) one is again realised as
>   my and the other as friend’s, whereas in (iib) they
>   combine in the single word mine’s. Both me’s and mine’s thus have
>   double-case marking, an inner case and an outer case. In me’s the
>   inner case is accusative, required because pronoun is object of the
>   preposition opposite, **while in (iib) the inner case is genitive
>   because the pronoun is functioning in the oblique genitive
>   construction.** The phrasal genitive is the outer case, morphologically added to the form that realise the inner case. In examples like `[the King of England’s] daughter`, the inner case of England is the plain case, which has no morphological marking, but the principle is the same: the outer genitive is added to form required by England within the inner NP “the king of England”.
>
> pg 479-480

I can barely see [in front of me] is [oblique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_case) because the pronoun “me” can be the object of either the verb (see?) or a preposition (of). English does not have distinct prepositional forms of pronouns. The same set of object pronouns are used after verbs and prepositions (e.g. watch **him**, look at **him**). However "of me" is a **non-core complement** indirectly related to the verb (see) through the preposition "of". "Of me" is a complement of see, but the NP `me` is an oblique.

> Wikipedia defines oblique case as:
>
> (aka. *objective case*) a nominal case that is used when a noun phrase is the object of either
>   a verb or a preposition
>
> An objective case is marked on the English personal pronouns and as
>   such serves the role of the accusative and dative cases that other
>   Indo-European languages employ. These forms are often called object
>   pronouns, and as **serve a variety of grammatical functions which they
>   would not in the languages that differentiate the two**; an example
>   using first person singular objective pronoun me:
>
> **as the object of a preposition (except in possessives)** :
>
> ? That picture of me was blurry.
>
> ? (cf. That picture of mine was blurry.)
>
> `Of me` is oblique because object pronouns such as `me` in English does not have distinct prepositional forms of pronouns. The **same set of object pronouns** are used after verbs and prepositions.

---

While “me” can either be an object of preposition with “of me” as a separate PP in “In front of me”

or

“of me” as an internal dependent/“adjective” in pre-head position of a "foot in front of me"—a word in the pre-head position are traditionally called attributive. CaGEL does not make this clear on page 439—whether it is a complement or modifier.

---

- [In this fog] is a PP with a NP compliment

---

Note that a PP can have a NP complement and a NP can have a PP as complement as claimed by BillJ:

> 1) I’m looking for **my glasses** - PP with a NP as complement
>
> 2) Where’s the key **to the safe**? - NP with PP as complement
>
> **But PP's do not work as NP's; they are a separate and distinct phrasal category with their own functions.**
>
> Source: [noun phrases vs. prepositional phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359234/noun-phrases-vs-prepositional-phrases)
>
> ---

To answer your question:

- **Barely** is an adverb
- **'Foot' by itself is a noun** (and even if it were a modifier/complement it would only **function** as an "adjective"). Because of this, function and lexical categories are not the same. Therefore, the lexical category of 'foot' is a noun. Whether it functions as an adverb is debatable and further complicated by the presence of an **oblique genitive NP**.
- In terms of categories, 'foot' is not an adverb as it does not have an adjectival base nor can it be suffixed with an -ly ending.
- 'Foot' could be an an internal dependent (compliment or modifier) in a larger NP “a foot in front of **me**” which has a PP as compliment: “in this fog”.
- If above is correct, "of me" is the object to "a foot" in the larger NP "a foot in front of me"; while the object of "see" in "I can barely see" is "in this fog".
- The verb `see` could be an **oblique ditransitive verb**, which takes 2 objects. `See`’s 2 objects could be “foot” or “fog". More on this concept can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb).
- The lexical category noun can never be the lexical category adverb
- The sentence is just *really* long.

Comment: Not everyone is familiar with abbreviation jargon that is used by linguists and experts. PP and NP need only be written in full the first time then people can figure the rest for themselves. I mean, PP can also stand for Present Participle, Present Perfect, Past Perfect, or Prepositional Phrase.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'll make this clearer.