Why is "second" an adverb in "came a close second"?
Consider the following example sentence excerpted from Oxford Learner's Dictionaries:

One of the smaller parties came a close second (= nearly won).

Much to my surprise, the example sentence is placed under the adverb entry, rather than the noun entry, of second, by the authors of the authoritative dictionary.
I just wonder: If second here is an adverb, why is the article a in front of it?
Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

I don't think the verb came is used transitively in your example. Rather, it's a linking verb and second is a subject complement (a noun here, not an adverb). a and close can then be treated as modifiers of second.

@user05662 Not a linking verb, I think, but simply an intransitive verb (used as a synonym for "finished"), with "a close second" as an adverbial phrase.

@chepner  Yes, it makes more sense to say that it's an intransitive verb.


[One of the smaller parties] came a close second.

Ordinal numbers like "first, second, third etc" are usually adjectives, but they can exceptionally be nouns, as evidenced by the presence of some  determiner like the article "a".
"Second" is then modified by the adjective "close" to give the idiomatic noun phrase "a close second", functioning as predicative complement of "came".

I've rephrased my question in the original post, pls review it. Thanks for your kind help.

@xmllmx Your rephrased question changes nothing. My answer still holds.

According to you, sound is a noun here. However, the dictionary counts it as an adverb; which confused me. Does it mean the authors of the dictionary make a mistake?

@xmllmx Don't rely on dictionaries for grammar. Consult a standard grammar book instead. Dictionaries can often be misleading in matters of grammar (as this example shows.)

@xmllmx What do you mean? There is no word "sound" in your example.

@BillJ, sorry for my typo. sound should be second.

@xmllmx "Second" is a noun. It must be because it has the article "a" as determiner. The dictionary is wrong.

The article "a" is used with nouns, so "second" can't be an adverb.
"Second" in "the second" is a noun; however "a second" has no meaning when "second" is a noun; a meaning can't be deduced from the meaning of "a" and "second" since there is only one thing or person in the second place; we are bound to conclude that "a close second" can't be analysed, that is to say, it is a fixed phrase and should be in an idiom section.  Since "a" is used it can be considered that "second" is a noun and the expression should be found in the idiom section under the noun.

What confused me is that the example senetence is placed under the adverb entry of second by the authoritative Oxford Learner's Dictionaries.
Does it make a mistake here?

@xmllmx I can't explain this otherwise than by an error in the lexicographical work. It is rare but it does happen.

@xmllmx It's not an error. It's just an omission, which always happens in mere learners' dictionaries. Those are always abridged for brevity and clarity. You need something that isn't abridged; the OED shows it as a noun in certain instances.

So it's a full moon today is also an idiom, because there's only one moon? This is not the way English works.

@PeterShor "Full 'moon" happens to be defined as a term different from "moon" in the OALD, of countability  "[C, usually sing.]", which nicely explains the possibility of use with the indefinite article. (The moon when it appears as a full circle; a time when this happens.)

@tchrist The phrase is found in the entry for the "adverb", so there is an error of some sort, if it is not analysis it has to be an error of attribution to the entries.

There are various adverbial expressions like "a bit", "a little" which start with "a" but can modify adjectives or adverbs ("They played a bit carelessly"). I'm not entirely sure "a close" functions the same way.

The OED does list "a close second" as an idiom/set phrase (under close adjective/adverb). I can't find it in other dictionaries.

@xmllmx see also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451677/can-a-noun-be-an-adverb

So are a clear sky, a cloudy sky, a bright sun, a blazing sun, a rising sun, a setting sun, an angry sun, an indifferent moon also idioms? My point is that a(n) adjective noun is perfectly cromulent English even if there's only one of the noun.

@PeterShor In the light of the definition for "full moon", provided we agree with the principle that underlies it, of course, no, they are not idioms but instead just as "full moon" they deserve definitions that set them apart from "sky" and "sun" as taken in their most basic sense. // The question whether "a + adj + noun" is acceptable is a matter of definition of the combination; you have such combinations as "a disgruntled Mr Leadbeater …" (https://www.google.fr/books/edition/A_Class_Act/-x7pDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22a+disgruntled+mr%22&pg=PT32&printsec=frontcover) (1/2)

@PeterShor where "a" adds new meaning to the phrase; however, there are grammatical records that permit to determine the interpretation; otherwise we deal in indefinition. Saying "A sun was not visible this morning." will leave everybody puzzled, it is not correct (borderline, if you consider an assimilation with "a adj sun"). In the case of "an angry sun, an indifferent moon" (rarely spoken), without having to refer to poetic license, and keeping to the domaine of literature, the analysis is, I think, no different than in the case of the well-known type I referred to above (a Mr).  (2/2)

And don't forget a distant last.

Except 'a close second' is not a set phrase: a distant second, a solid second, a poor second, etc. Are these all then idioms? Not to mention that 'a second' has perfectly good meaning:  The Phantom started three times in the big one with his best results being a second to Kingston Rule in 1990 after finishing fourth to Tawriffic the previous year Racing News. Hardly an idiom.

@DW256 "The OED does list "a close second" as an idiom/set phrase (under close adjective/adverb)", https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/623357/why-is-second-an-adverb-in-came-a-close-second/623361?noredirect=1#comment1589692_623361. Your reasoning is not logical: the sheer number of variants on the same  theme would be reason enough to justify a supposed regularity of the expression. What about "runs in the family"? (link for ngram not working, you'll have to check that yourself if need be: that, this, their, his, her, our, your)

@LPH Runs has idiomatic meaning there, second's meaning on the other hand can be readily discerned from its regular definition. The sheer number of variations possible with the noun 'second' show that it is simply a regular noun, capable of the standard range of uses and modifications.

@DW256 It is true also, as the conclusion to which your remarks lead, that the principle of compositionality is not infringed upon to a great extent ("second" preserves its meaning), but it remains to take into account the combination of the indefinite article with a noun that is never use with it. You can't say "he/she/I/… was a second in the race."; that does count too.

Which part of speech is second in The party came second? So wouldn't it be the same part of speech in The party came a close second? Which part of speech is many in The party received many votes ?  So wouldn't it be the same part of speech in The party received a good many votes?

I think that the word "second" here is a "flat adverb". In this context, it can be used interchangeably with "secondly".
See flat adverb on Wikipedia:

In English grammar, a flat adverb, bare adverb, or simple adverb is an adverb that has the same form as the corresponding adjective, so it usually does not end in -ly, e.g. "drive slow", "drive fast", "dress smart", etc. The term includes words that naturally end in -ly in both forms, e.g. "drive friendly". Flat adverbs were once quite common but have been largely replaced by their -ly counterparts.
[...]
Numerical adjectives (first, second, last) rarely are used in an -ly form despite having a valid alternative. While words like firstly and lastly exist, their flat form is much more commonly used. Here, in contrast to other flat adverbs such as good ("they cook good"), the flat form is universally accepted in English as proper speech.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Please include the information from the link.  Otherwise this is subject to link rot and doesn't include enough information that addresses the question.

The question is: why is it classified as an adverb at all, which seems grammatically wrong.
